# Declaring a pointer to a structure in its field

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I need to typedef the structure pointer then use the new type in its field.

I mean instead of doing :

```
struct app 
{
   char *data;
   struct app *ptr;
}
```

I need to typedef somewhere `typedef app* appPtr;` then use it like:

```
struct app 
{
   char *data;
   appPtr ptr;
}
```

How can i do such a thing ?

PS:i need to use both `appPtr` & `app` types.

Comment: Don't `typedef` pointers! This is a guarantee for confusion, as it hides the different semantics. Just `typedef` the `struct` itself.

Comment: I know its not recommended to typedef a pointer but i have to do so for a certain reason.Based on that supposition,how can i do it ? @Olaf

Comment: `typedef`-ing pointers is legal in C.  Its has rare good uses, if any.  I find that it is better to not use that construct.  Yet asking about how to do it does not make this post a poor question.

Answer (score 2):

It can be accomplished using *forward declaration* of `struct`. Here is an example code, that realizes that concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct app;
typedef struct app* appPtr;

struct app 
{
   char *data;
   appPtr ptr;
};

int main(void)
{
   struct app myApp = { "myApp", NULL };

   printf("%s, %p\n", myApp.data, (void *) myApp.ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

However, as mentioned in question's comments I wouldn't recommend it as proper practice, because it obfuscates the code and things go messy with more levels of indirection.